# Bootstrap 4 modal scale with content

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4 modal, the modal basically just contain an image. Right now I set my modal dialog max-width to 95%. Whenever the modal opens, it's always 95%, which looks good when the image is large. But when there's a tiny image, the modal is still 95% width and there's the tiny image, which doesn't look really good.

How do I scale the modal so that if the image is big, the width will be 95% but if the image is small, it will adjust to the max-width of that image?

the css file, most of this code is just to make the modal appear in the center of the screen

```css
.modal-dialog {
  min-height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 60px);
  min-height: -moz-calc(100vh - 60px);
  min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img [src]="picture" alt="large picture" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would sugest to use

```
.modal-body {
  margin:auto;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

or add bootstrap class to the box

```
<div class="modal-body  mx-auto mw-100 ">
```

Listing can be found here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/ & https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

*If that does not work, please , let us know and update your snippet with enough code to show your issue live ;)*

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work in my case. I just put an image of 1000px in the `modal-body` DIV, and the image extruded on the right edge of the modal. At last, I use the solution found [here](https://codepen.io/JacobLett/pen/MOJPRW) to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could load the image in background, in a hidden container and when it's loaded, get its size and readjust the modal's width consequently.